# Unable to correctly sort file according to the creation date

Tags: python, time

I would like to sort some files according to the creation date. I use the function getctime from os library. It seems to no work on my code... I may do something wrong. It should work nevertheless if I understood the getctime function ... "Return the system’s ctime which, on some systems (like Unix) is the time of the last metadata change, and, on others (like Windows), is the creation time for path. The return value is a number giving the number of seconds since the epoch"

'''python

```
##getting creating date time
creation_date_list = []    
for file_name in list_file_name:
    path_file = os.path.join(PATH,file_name)
    creation_date_list.append(os.path.getctime(path_file))
creation_date_list.sort()

for element in creation_date_list:
    creation_date_temp = 0
    index = 0
    temp_list = []
    while(creation_date_temp != element):
        path_file = os.path.join(PATH,list_file_name[index])
        creation_date_temp = os.path.getctime(path_file)
        index = index+1
    temp_list.append(list_file_name[index-1])
    temp_list.append(element)
    list_detailed_file.append(temp_list)
```

'''

It should give me a list of file name sorted according to the creation date. Did I do a mistake ?

Thank you very much

Comment: try using `getmtime` instead of `getctime` may be helpful.

Comment: I've never been able to work out what `getctime()` was good for. @AmazingThingsAroundYou is right. Use `getmtime()` instead.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answers ! I will try it. But getmtime() should return the modification date instead of creation date...

Comment: It works ! Nevertheless, my files have been never modificated. So I think that the modification date should be the creation date. (even if it is not the case)